# Keras - coding a custom optimizer and attempting to compute a second gradient inside get_updates

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am a researcher in optimization and I trying to write a custom optimizer. I have come across a problem. I have asked in many places and so far no response.

Take any optimizer code, say just copy SGD. In the beginning of get_updates, you see

```
grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
```

now add the following line right after this one:

```
gradsb = self.get_gradients(loss, [tf.Variable(a) for a in params])
```

this should compute the gradients at a new tensor, with all the values the same as before

now try to see what you get:

```
for a in gradsb:
   print(a)
```

you get a list of Nones (but if you print the list grads you see that they are still Tensors)

Why?
And how to circumvent this problem? This is important as I'd like to compute the gradients at another point for my algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

When you write  `gradsb = self.get_gradients(loss, [tf.Variable(a) for a in params])` you are defining a new `tf.Variable` for each `a` in params. Because the loss does not depend on these new variables, your gradients are `None`.

If you want to compute a second gradient you need to make sure that you're computing it with respect to `Tensors` that the objective does depend on.

Comment: Thank you very much

So in practice how can you treat the loss function in a modular way? If inside get_updates I do not want to change the current variables until the end of the function, but I would like to compute the gradient of the loss function with respect to a new set of variable tensors, how would I do that?

Comment: `tf.gradients` lets you compute the gradient of any tensor with respect to any other tensor.

Comment: Yes, of course. But in this case I need to calculate the gradient of the loss function with respect to the tensors it depends on, but evaluated at a point different than the current value of the tensors in "params"

OK, I can save the current values of params in another tensor, then change params to be equal the new point at which I wish to evaluate the gradient, evaluate the new gradient, then afterwards assign params to its original list of tensor values...but this seems odd/inefficient, surely there is a more appropriate way?

Comment: Not a much more efficient way, since to compute the gradient you need to compute the forward pass. You can get it in a single session.run call if you build two graphs.

Comment: please see my answer above as it did not fit in the comment box. Thank you @alexandre-passos

Answer (score 0):

Apparently even replacing the current vector of parameters is not OK!! If I type this in the code:

```
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    tempparam = [tf.Variable(a) for a in params]
    params = [tf.add(a,a) for a in params]

    gradsn = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    for a in gradsn:
        print(a)
    params = [tf.Variable(a) for a in tempparam]
```

The result is still that None is printed!!

I know you understand what I am trying to do, at each iteration of get_updates, I would like to compute the gradients at a (slightly) different value of the parameter tensors, and use that to construct the update to the parameters for optimization and training. Is there any way to do this within the keras package?

Comment: When I say "rebuild the graph" I mean "recompute loss", so call get_gradients again with the new set of params.

Comment: that is what I am attempting to do with the line that has

gradsn = self.get_gradients(loss, params)

shouldn't this do the forward and backward pass? Or do I need to call another function to evaluate the loss first?

Comment: or specifically what do I need to add before that statement of get_gradients in order to achieve what I need to here?

Comment: You need to recompute loss, so something like `other_loss = self.compute_loss(params); gradsn = self.get_gradients(other_loss, params)`

Comment: self.compute_loss is not a valid function. I tried looking for a backend function to compute it without success, do you know what I should call to compute the loss and perform the forward pass? Thank you

Comment: That really depends on how your model is defined. You need to rerun the model definition code to build this alternative graph.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am using fairly standard keras workflow. In the main part of the python script I have model = Sequential() then model.add various layers then model.compile and model.fit.

Surely there is  away to compute a new loss within get_updates?

Comment: Make another model, or use two session.run calls